# invalid operands of type 'int' to 'int*' to binary 'operator*'

Tags: c

I am working on a program that swaps two integer variables.  When I compile I get an error

> invalid operands of type 'int' to 'int*' to binary 'operator*'

on line 30 (Second last line).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap_2(int *x, int *y);

int main(void)
{
    int i1, i2;

    printf("Enter two integers\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &i1, &i2);
    printf("i1 = %d\n", i1);
    printf("i2 = %d\n", i2);

    printf("Swap integers\n");
    swap_2(&i1, &i2);
    printf("i1 = %d\n", i1);
    printf("i2 = %d\n", i2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void swap_2(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *x;
    *x = *y
    *y = temp;      **//LINE 30**
}
```

Comment: Check for missing semi-colons...

Comment: do you even know how to read compiler output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on line 29.

```
void swap_2(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *x;
    *x = *y  <----------- missing semicolon
    *y = temp;      **//LINE 30**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap_2(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *x;
    *x = *y
    *y = temp;      **//LINE 30**
}
```

You have a missing colon at the end of line 29"

Try:

```
*x = *y;
```

Comment: That's embarrassing, it is possible to take this question down?